# How to find the distance using dot product from point $A$ to the line through $B$ and $C$?

Tags: calculus

How to find the distance using dot product from point $A$ to the line through $B$ and $C$?

The points are $A = (2, -6, 1)$, $B = (3, 4, -2)$ and $C = (7, -1, 5)$.

I have tried this method: $$d=\frac{||BC \times BA||}{||BC||}$$

Please tell me how to find the distance using dot product.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478765/find-the-shortest-distance-between-the-point-8-3-2-and-the-line-through-the).

Answer (score 1):

The line throguh points $\;B,C\;$ can be put (parametrized) as

$$l_{BC}: B+t\vec{BC}=(3,4,-2)+t(4,-5,7)=(3+4t\,,\,4-5t\,,\,-2+7t)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

Thus, a vector from $\;A\;$ to a general point $\;Q\;$ on the line is parametrized as

$$\vec{AQ}=(3+4t,\,4-5t,\,-2+7t)-(2,-6,1)=(1+4t\,,\,10-5t\,,\,-3+7t)$$

Finally, we need that

$$\;0=\langle A\,,\,\vec{AQ}\rangle=2+8t+12+30t-3+7t\implies45t=-11\implies t=-\frac{45}{11}$$

Complete now the exercise.

Comment: Your $\vec{AQ}$ is incorrect.

Comment: @linear_combinatori_probabi  Indeed, though merely writing "it is incorrect" without saying what the mistake is isn't as helpful. Anyway,. this is more than 6.5 years old and the OP, or whoever is trying to learn somethiong from this, should check the work carefully..

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
use the property that v1.v2=0 , if v1,v2 are perpendicular.

OK.so, let A(2,-6,1); B(3,4,-2); C(7,-1,5) be given.
Now lets  find BC vector, which comes BC(4,-5,7).
Now suppose a point P(x,y,z) in between B and C.and draw perpendicular from A to this point P .
We can find AP vector which is AP(x-2,4+6,z-1).
now dot product of AP and BC is zero. From here you get P.Once you have P. The |AP| is the required distance

Comment: Plz make me more clear I didn't understand

Comment: @ketan, your answers wont't be fully appreciated (and perhaps not even read) if you don't learn how to use LaTeX to properly write mathematics in this site...a pity.

Comment: Answer is not right by your method,answer is 7.75 but I'm getting 69 by your method,Is point P is(0,0,45/7)?